# Move a random element from one array to another

Tags: javascript, arrays

hey so i have an array with 8 sounds in it and right now i have it so when i click on an image a random sound from the array plays, its moved to a new array, and when the original array of sounds is empty then the new array will transfer the songs back to the original array.

`-the problem is that when it removes the sound its not the sound that was just played.`

`-also id like to make clicking on the image multiple times not do anything other than playing the one sound until it finishes(then its moved to the empty array),then you can click the image for a new random sound`

```
var sounds = [
"https://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/numbers/1.wav",
"https://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/numbers/2.wav",
"https://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/numbers/3.wav",
"https://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/numbers/4.wav",
"https://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/numbers/5.wav",
"https://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/numbers/6.wav",
"https://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/numbers/7.wav",
"https://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/numbers/8.wav"
];

var oldSounds = [];

function playSound()
{
var randomSound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length)];

document.getElementById("player").innerHTML=
"<embed src=\""+randomSound+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";

//splice randomSound from sounds array into var removed
//than push that sound into oldSounds array
var removed = sounds.splice(randomSound, 1);
oldSounds.push(removed);
console.log("==song removed from sound array = " + removed);
console.log(" .sounds length = " + sounds.length);
console.log(" .oldSounds length = " + oldSounds.length);

//if all sounds played from sound array AND all sounds are now in oldSounds array
//than move the sounds  from oldSounds to sounds
if (sounds.length === 0 && oldSounds.length === 8)
{
    console.log("----------------");
    sounds = oldSounds;
    console.log("sounds length = " + sounds.length);
    oldSounds = [];
    console.log("oldSounds length = " + oldSounds.length);
    console.log("----------------");
}
}
```

this is what i have so far : http://jsbin.com/sekajumeva/1/edit?html,js,console,output

any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: some code will be better? not just jsbin?

Comment: Please think of a better title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, [**splice**()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) takes an `index` as a first parameter, and you are passing the sound url.

To fix your code, transform this:

```
var removed = sounds.splice(randomSound, 1);
```

into this:

```
var removed = sounds.splice(sounds.indexOf(randomSound), 1);
```

I haven't tested because honestly I can't here any sound, but see if that works, happy new year!

Comment: I was just trying to be nice though :)

Comment: Fair enough. I'll remove the other comment. As far as the answer, of course you are correct, but I'd suggest storing the index in a variable at the point where the random number is generated.

Comment: It's okey, happy new year!

Comment: No problem, happy coding :) (pd: If you feel like your question's been asnwered click the green tick next to the answer)

Answer (score 1):

THe problem should comes from the `splice`.
it returns an array, when you push to the `oldSounds`, it would be array in array which is not what you want? Correct one would be >>

```
var removed = sounds.splice(randomSound, 1);
oldSounds.push(removed[0]);
```

question number 2, you can make a variable to hold the state.
for example state of `playing`. Init a state with default `false` like `var isPlaying = false`. then in your `playSound()` fiunction, you will check the state, if it is playing, just return. `if (isPlaying) {return;} else {isPlaying = true}`.. remember at the end of function `playSound`, set the flag back to false `isPlaying= false`

```
var isPlaying = false;
function playSound() {
  if (isPlaying) {
   return;
  }
  isPlaying = true; // set the state to true, if using click the image again, this function will not be called because returned on the `if` on top

  // ur original codes
  var randomSound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length)];
  document.getElementById("player").innerHTML=
    "<embed src=\""+randomSound+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";

  ....
  isPlaying = false; // set the state back to false, so the music will be played
}
```

Comment: great it helps :) just added my personally recommendation for 2nd question.

Comment: so what would i set to isPlaying? If its the document.getElementById("player").... how would i set that to isPlaying?

Comment: it can be anything, jsut a flag/state holder for the function :) i don't understand what do you mean by `If its the document.getElementById("player").... how would i set that to isPlaying?` i updated the codes again above

Comment: oh ok my bad lol... i thought you meant set something else to isPlaying. thanks for the help.

Comment: ok so i played around with it trying to get it to work, but i cant seem to make it work. can you expand on it a little more? i tried using document.getElementById("a").onclick = false; so that when you click the image and its playing, it wont let you click again

Comment: oh, you're going for another approach. Your approach is unset the `onClick` event listener, but you would need to attach it back later on after the playing was complete. For me this would be a little bit tricky, i still prefer the approach that introduce a `flag` variable to hold the state, and use that flag (isPlaying) to determine if we want to play the music as suggested above

Comment: so for the isplaying if statement, is it an if else statement where the embedding part is in the else part? because i dont see how it would tell that the song is playing

Comment: all your other codes are remains, just adding additional that `if` statement :) the `...` on tops means your original codes

Comment: ya ive been trying how u said and its not working....clicking the image still plays a sound after multiple image clicks. it doesnt wait for the sound to finish

Comment: http://jsbin.com/wuqadetohi/3/edit  i've been overlooked that we need to listen to the event of the embedded element. the `isPlaying` shouldnot set in the `playSound` function but through the play ended callback. i changed the `embed` to `audio` which is the HTML5 element, this doc shows more the [event information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)

Answer (score 0):

So your code is:

```
var sounds = [
    "https://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/numbers/1.wav",
    "https://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/numbers/2.wav",
    ...
];

var oldSounds = [];

function playSound()
{
    var randomSound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length)];
```

So *randomSound* will be something like "https://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/numbers/2.wav". Then:

```
    document.getElementById("player").innerHTML=
    "<embed src=\""+randomSound+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";

    //splice randomSound from sounds array into var removed
    //than push that sound into oldSounds array
    var removed = sounds.splice(randomSound, 1);
```

The first argument to *splice* should be an index (0, 1, 2, etc.) but you are passing the above string. That will be converted to 0 (see [*Array.prototype.splice step 5*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.120)), so you'll just keep splicing the first member of the array.

It would be better to do something like:

```
var indexToPlay = Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length);
var randomSound = sounds[indexToPlau];

...

var removed = sounds.splice(indexToPlay, 1);
```